# Data structure for counting combination occurrences

Tags: data-structures

I have a bunch of symbols, say `{A, B, C, ....}`, and a dataset. I need to counting every combination occurrences such as `{AB, AC, ..., ABC, ..., BC, ...}`. The number of symbols may up to 100 or more. But many of the combination are not appeared.

The first solution I could use a `map<string, integer>`, but I think it waste of memory. The second solution I could use is trie, which share the prefix. The third solution could be a tree, but it needs a tree per symbol. I don't know if it is better than trie.

So do you have any suggest?

Comment: If the set is S and you have a binary number of |S| bits, it can be used to represent any subset. The 1's correspond to elements present in the set. Now you need only to count from 0 to 2^N-1 and emit the set corresponding to each value.  Note that if |S|=100 or anything close to it, it will take over 30 trillion years to enumerate them all at 1 per nanosecond.

Comment: Are you looking for combinations or permutations? With permutations, `AB` and `BA` are considered different. With combinations, `AB` and `BA` are considered the same thing.

Comment: @Gene It seems to be the BitMAP algorithm? It really solve part of the problem that is finding the subset. But there is another problem behind it: I need to count each subset individually in order to make the frequent combination prior to the infrequent ones. Do you have any further suggestion?

Comment: @JimMischel It is combination, not permutation. The order of element is ignored.

Comment: Using a `map<string, integer>` is the straightforward way, and if you have the memory to spare, quite reasonable. My suggestion would be to use that unless there's some reason you can't. If it works, and works fast enough in your application, then use it. Only worry about optimizing memory or processor cycles when it really matters.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea what this sentence means: "I need to count each subset individually in order to make the frequent combination prior to the infrequent ones."  Using a bitmap will produce each combination exactly once. They're all trivially equally frequent.  Do you mean the subsets need to be ordered by size?

Answer (score 0):

From the comments I *think* you're saying you need to enumerate the subsets in order of increasing size. One way is a simple recursion:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char set[] = "ABCD";
char buf[100];

void e(char *s, int len, int size, int p) {
  if (size == 0) {
    buf[p] = '\0';
    printf("{%s}\n", buf);
    return;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i <= len - size; ++i) {
    buf[p] = s[i];
    e(s + i + 1, len - i - 1, size - 1, p + 1);
  }
}

int main(void) {
  int len = strlen(set);
  for (int size = 0; size <= len; ++size) e(set, len, size, 0);
  return 0;
}
```

Here's a run:

```
$ ./foo
{}
{A}
{B}
{C}
{D}
{AB}
{AC}
{AD}
{BC}
{BD}
{CD}
{ABC}
{ABD}
{ACD}
{BCD}
{ABCD}
```

There are several other approaches. If you want the set sizes to be in some other order, this method is still a good starting point.

Comment: Actually it is not what I want. The key point you have ignored in the problem is that there is a dataset. This problem is extracted from another problem, and it is just a part of that problem. I am not trying to enumerate each combination, but to counting the occurrences of combinations in the dataset.